# SQL query counting stats - counting if this is the first record in a table for a particular user

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building some basic stats/reporting into a CRM system built in php/mysql.

Consider the query:

```
 SELECT
    count(m.id) as student_count,
    SUM(if(m.membership_expiry >= "2021-06-30 00:00:00", 1, 0)) AS member_count,
    SUM(if(m.distance_from_college = "Unknown", 1, 0)) as unknown_count,
    SUM(if(m.distance_from_college = "Within 20 miles", 1, 0)) as w20_count,
    SUM(if(m.distance_from_college = "20-50 miles", 1, 0)) as 20t50_count,
    SUM(if(m.distance_from_college = "50-100 Miles", 1, 0)) as 50t100_count,
    SUM(if(m.distance_from_college = "100-200 miles", 1, 0)) as 100t200_count,
    SUM(if(m.distance_from_college = "200+ miles", 1, 0)) as 200p_count,
    SUM(if(m.country != "GB", 1, 0)) as int_count
FROM
    cps_booking AS b
LEFT JOIN 
    cps_member AS m ON b.user_id = m.id AND m.deleted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
LEFT JOIN
    cps_product AS p ON b.product_id = p.id AND p.deleted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
WHERE
    b.status = "Confirmed" AND
    b.deleted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" AND
    p.type != "On-Demand" AND p.type != "Consultation" AND
    p.start_date BETWEEN "2021-06-01 00:00:00" AND "2021-06-30 23:59:59"
```

This is working so far to return the desired statistics but I am struggling for the best way to identify new students.
For the purposes of this report a new student would be any user_id for whom the current record would be their first entry in the cps.booking table.

Any clever solutions?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is probably an `uncorrelated subquery` as part of the `select`. Here is an example of implementation.

```
select
    ....
    ....,
    (select count(user_id) from cps_booking group by user_id having count(*)=1)
from
   ....
```

This is assuming you're only concerned with `cps_booking` table and don't have duplicated records for a given user_id.
A couple of notes if helpful:

MySQL evaluates conditions to 1 or 0. That means you could just do `SUM(m.country != "GB")` instead of `SUM(if(m.country != "GB", 1, 0))`

I also noticed you split the conditions for `cps_product` between `left join` and `where` clause. You might want to move them over to the `left join` so you don't end up with an `inner join` by proxy.

Comment: Thanks Phil - great solution & really appreciate you spotting my Friday afternoon error on the mixed where clause locations.